# What rating of constant current LED driver do I need?

Tags: led, led-strip, led-driver

I've recently finished building some understairs cupboards.

I fitted a 9W LED light into the cupboard which comes on when the cupboard opens. It is driven from this LED driver.

[image: LED driver]

I've measured the DC voltage on the output of the LED driver with the light on and it is showing as 27VDC.

Unfortunately, the shelves are really dark as you can see.

[image: Shelves]

So I had the idea of fitting rigid LED strips into them.

I thought I could just buy 30VDC LED lights and they would work. I found the following strips on eBay.
[Rigid LED lights](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Rigid-LED-Strip-39SMD-12v-10-30v-DC-7W-Cool-White-52cm-1163/111315261380?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&var=410305998370&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)

Unfortunately, the seller of these has said that the 30VDC capacity is only really for 'spikes' and they are more designed to run at 24VDC (for caravans etc).

I also looked for a 'beefier' LED driver and found this on Amazon.
[1500mA LED Driver](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B01N25KCGI/ref=pe_942301_45935611_TE_FOCE_n_id)

It was then I read about the difference between "constant current" drivers and "constant voltage" drivers.

At this point I was completely lost so thought I would ask the experts for some advice and guidance.

I'm looking for help on what LED driver I would need to achieve this. I wondered if a "constant current" driver would just inject that current (1500mA) into it's output at all times and potentially damage the existing light and the new LEDs?

Also, whether 24VDC LEDs would be suitable?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please show a diagram of how you connected it. A constant current drivers requires all LEDs to be in series. If you want to expand it, you need to break it open whereas a constant voltage system is easier to just parallel in more as you go.

Comment: How much light do you need to see what shoes to pick?. If it's really as dark as you say it is, I suggest a hand-held, battery powered torch/flashlight. Fitting lights on each shelf is OCD and wastes energy.

Comment: @Andyaka You can't call yourself an engineer if you don't have OCD! :-)

Comment: Yeah but my OCD is special OCD! @winny

Comment: @winny at the moment there is only one LED light in that part of the cupboard. It is connected to the LED driver that came with it (in the photo above). So I just have mains in one end of the LED driver and the DC at the other end going to the light. I (wrongly - it seems) assumed I could just replace my LED driver for a beefier one and then run the original LED light and some LED strips in parallel?

Comment: @Andyaka you sound exactly like my wife!! You're right, I could do without it. It is just something I would like to do as my eye-sight isn't brilliant and, on the dark mornings, I sometimes find it hard to see my work shoes. However, I could go and put on the big light or, as you suggest, buy a torch, but I would like to do this if possible.

Comment: That’s the downside of constant current, you practically can’t parallel LEDs. You need to get a beefier in terms of double the voltage (yours is 30 V max forward voltage and you are using 27 V of it) and same current and run them in series. Or get one LED driver for each.

Comment: @winny thanks for that. Is it possible to just change my LED driver for a 'constant voltage' one. Then get one that is 24VDC and can cope with the parallel load of the original LED light and the new LED strips? Or are there LED lights that *only* work with 'constant current' hence a constant current driver being shipped with the light as standard?

Comment: You put your head right on the nail there (Swedish proverb)! The LED chip itself always expect CC but a CV LED board/module is built with either a full on driver or just a current limiting resistor (99.99 % of all flexible LED strips) to make it accept CV input. Your existing one is without resistor if it’s meant for CC operation.

Comment: Wait wait! Scratch that. Is it exactly the one in the link? In that case you have the wrong driver for it in the first place!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97979/discussion-between-winny-and-john-t).

Answer (score 3):

A constant voltage supply will output its rated voltage at any current up to the maximum it is built to supply.  If overloaded, it should shut down.  They come in standardised voltages, such as 12V or 24V.

A constant current supply will deliver whatever voltage it needs to, in order to push its rated current through the LEDs.  So a 1500mA supply will keep ramping up the voltage until 1500mA flows.  This will be subject to a maximum voltage that the power supply can deliver, such as 30V.

Selecting the wrong sort of power supply is liable to either overload the power supply or blow the LEDs.

If you're using 12V LED strips, then you need a 12V constant voltage supply, with a wattage rating high enough for the sum of the wattages of all the strips.

Comment: thank you for the answer. The LED strips I found will work up to 30VDC at a push but are happier around 24VDC according to the seller. So, is it best to replace my 'constant current' LED drivers with 'constant voltage' instead?

Comment: @JohnT the seller recommends a 12V or 24V constant voltage supply.  You could calculate the current that the strips would draw, and then get a matching constant current one, but it may be hard to predict the brightness you would get.

Comment: thanks for that. That's the way I'm leaning at the moment. :-)